# Why does this tend to $\ln|2|$

Tags: limits, logarithms

May I know why is this true?
When $k \to 0$, $\frac{2^k -1}{k} \to \ln|2| $.
From what I can see, this fraction would tend to $\frac{0}{0}$, which has no exact value. And  if you use L'Hospital's law, it still does not tend to $\ln|2|$.
 Thank you very much for you guys reply.

Comment: This question is taken from an exam paper, and the answer is ln|2|...

Comment: What do you get when you apply L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: $\frac{k2^{k-1}}{1}$ with $ k \to 0$.

Comment: By that reasoning, $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = x e^{x-1}$. You're taking the derivative of an exponential, not of the nth power of a function. You should apply the formula $\frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \ln a$.

Comment: @Brian, Thank you for your reply sir, I don't quite get why I am taking the derivative of an exponential... sorry for any inconvenience caused. And think $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$

Comment: Btw nothing tends to $0/0$. You should say that both numerator and denominator of a fraction tend to $0$ and in such a case we need more analysis to determine the limit of the fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By L'Hospital's rule,

$$
\lim\limits_{k \to 0} \frac{2^k -1}{k} =  \lim\limits_{k \to 0} \frac{(\ln 2) (2^k) }{1} = \ln 2.
$$
Since the second limit converges, the first converge to the same value.

Based on your comments, it appears that you are applying the formula for the derivative of a power of some variable $x$, 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}\quad \text{ where $n\in \Bbb R$ }
$$

when you in fact are dealing with an exponential of $x$, which satisfies
$$
\frac{d}{dx} a^x = (\ln a)x^{a}\quad \text{ where $a$ > 0}
$$

Comment: Thank you sir, so I have used lobita's law wrongly. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: It's actually i failed to notice the derivative of $a^x$. Thank you.. I made a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

set $2^{k}-1=t$

then we have:
$$\lim_{k\to0}\frac{2^{k}-1}{k}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t}{\log_{2}\left(t+1\right)}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{\frac{\log_{2}\left(t+1\right)}{t}}=\frac{1}{\log_{2}\left(\lim_{t\to0}(t+1\right))^{\large\frac{1}{t}}}=\frac{1}{\log_{2}\left(e\right)}=\ln\left(2\right)$$

Here I used the fact that $\log_{2}\left(u\right)$ is continuous over its domain.

Comment: Thank you very much. This proof is beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the rate of variation from the value $x=0$ of the function $x\mapsto 2^x$. By definition, this is the derivative of $2^x$ at $x=0$. Now, for any $a>0$,
$$(a^x)'=\bigl(\mathrm e^{x\ln a}\bigr)'=\mathrm e^{x\ln a}\ln a=a^x\ln a.$$

Comment: thank you very much.